# Apache JMeter - listener results interpretation

Tags: jmeter

I use JMeter to test my webapp application, I have aggregate graph with some score values, but I actually don't know what they mean...

Aggregate graph shows for example:

- average
- median
- min
- max

I don't know about what refer that values.

For what refer 90% line?
I also don't know what's the unit of throughput per second (bytes?).
Anybody knows?
JMeter documentation shows only general information about reports and listeners.

Comment: some good jmeter stuff is given at http://jmeter-expert.blogspot.in/.

Comment: `http://jmeterresults.blogspot.in/2012/07/jmeterunderstanding-summary-report.html` --this link may also be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130063502/http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/) contains a helpful explanation for Jmeter Usuage, Results, Tips, Considerations and Deployment.

Good Luck!

Comment: [more TIPS](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2005/jw-0711-jmeter.html) on conducting an accurate test.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 9):

**Throughput** - means number of requests per one second. So if two users open your website at the same time throughput will be 2/s - 2 requests in one second.

How it can be useful: check your website analytics and you see number of hosts and hits per one day. Throughput stands for hits per day. If analytics shows 200 000 hits per day this means: 200 000 / 86400 (seconds in one day) = 2,31 hits/s.

**Average** - the average of response time. I think you know what is response time - it's time between sending request and getting response from server. To get the average response time you should sum all samplers response time and devide to number of samplers. Sampler means user, request, hit, the meaning is the same.

**Min** - the minimal response time in all samplers. Differently we may say the fastest response.

**Max** - opposite of Min, the slowest response.

Answer (score 3):

The throughput is generally measured in requests/second in things Jmeter.

As far as knowing what requests are within the 90% line, not really a way to do it with this listener. This is representing aggregate information, so it only reports on information about all the tests, not specific results.

For some different methods and ideas on getting useful information out of the responses, take a look at this jmeter wiki on [log analysis](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/LogAnalysis).

If you don't already have it, [jmeter plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) has a lot of useful controllers and listeners that can make understanding the results easier as well.